# How to implement a smooth simultaneous run and jump action like Super Marios using Spritekit

Tags: sprite-kit

In old school Mario (in video arcades) we had 1 lever to control direction and another button to jump. We use to hold the direction lever and occasionally push the button. The effect was Mario running and jumping at SAME time. How to get that effect in iOS Spritekit. I can make it run, I can make it jump. Having difficulty doing it simultaneously to product smooth mario like effect

Comment: Can you show some code? What is your current approach? Are you using the physics engine?

Comment: Game is physics based but the player (which i need to jump) has isDynamic disabled (so, I will be managing its movement) and here are methods           func move(target: CGPoint) {
    guard let physicsBody = physicsBody else { return }
    
    let newVelocity = (target - position).normalized() * PlayerSettings.playerSpeed
    physicsBody.velocity = CGVector(point: newVelocity)
  }

func jump(){
    player.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 10, dy: 10))
 }

Comment: If you have isDynamic disabled then you shouldn't be moving the player with the physics body. Turn isDynamic off if you are moving it with applyImpulse, etc.

Comment: True . I am learning Spritekit...:) Slowly